# Are there any valid reasons not to use fread() and fwrite() over read.csv() and write.csv()?

Tags: r, csv, data.table, read.csv

`fread()` and `fwrite()` are part of the `data.table` package in R and they perform significantly faster than the base `read.csv()` and `write.csv()` functions.

As I work with enormous csv files (several GB in size), I now find myself always using `fread()` and `fwrite()` over the base functions `read.csv()` and `write.csv()` as they perform significantly faster.

I am now beginning to wonder if there are any valid reasons (as opposed to mere opinion) where `read.csv()` and `write.csv()` perform better than `fread()` and `fwrite()`.

Are there any such reasons?

Comment: The dedicated read and write methods for CSV take stuff such as escaping and field delimiters into account, whereas with normal read-write methods you would have to take care of that yourself.

Comment: No, there aren't.

Comment: `fwrite` can write datatables with list columns

Comment: only reason I can think of is avoiding package dependencies (not a big thing, but a tie-breaker)

Comment: It's somewhat tautological, but you should use read.csv when fread has failed. It might still not work, but it's worth a try if the csvs are small.

Answer (score 4):

One thing the basic read functions from the `utils` package can do that `fread` cannot is read data from any type of text connection.

For example, assume there's an archive named `sample.zip`, and in this archive is a file named `sample.csv` with the following lines:

```
A,B
1,x
2,y
```

`read.csv` can read that file without extracting it:

```
zipcon <- unz("sample.zip", "sample.csv")
base_result <- read.csv(zipcon)
base_result
#   A B
# 1 1 x
# 2 2 y
```

`fread` cannot:

```
library(data.table)

zipcon <- unz("sample.zip", "sample.csv")
dt_result <- fread(zipcon)
# Error in fread(zipcon) : 
#   'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a command,
#   full path to a file, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://',
#   or the input data itself
```